Can't access details field on journals created from Rev Rec
I need to access the details listing on the "lines" of Journal Entry Records created from Rev Rec in SuiteScript or saved search. This field is not visible in edit mod. Is there some other way to get access to that data?
thanks in advance.
I Tried all the possible ways.
